# How to take results from json input and put into a csv output in python

Tags: json, python-2.7, pandas, csv

I am trying to work out how to take results from python regarding the sentiment polarity of tweets (original input from json file) and turn them into a csv i can export for use in R - im using Python 2.7

I have tried a couple of different ways from similar stackflow queries, but no success so far.

For example, using pandas package

```
tweet_polarity = []
for tweet in tweet_text:
    polarity = analyser.polarity_scores(tweet[1])   
    tweet_polarity.append([tweet[0], tweet[1], polarity['compound'],
                      polarity['neg'], polarity['neu'], polarity['pos']])


import pandas 
df = pandas.DataFrame(data={"tweet_polarity": tweet_polarity, "tweet_text": tweet_text,
                        "tweets}": tweets})
df.to_csv("polarityRES.csv")
```

creates a csv file, but seems to just repeat the same tweet over and over again rather than creating a nice dataframe with the polarity scores

I thought about using cvs.writer, but haven't been able to find a relevant example to what I'm trying to do. Any suggestions gang?

(Sorry for my terrible explanation, I'm still getting to grips with the basics while trying to do this - and typing one handed with tendonitis!)

Comment: Do you mind providing a sample of the json file?

Comment: is 'tweet_text' a list of tweets? what is the output of polarity_scores() method?